# unable to read/write data to .plist file in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, plist, epub

i am new to iPhone developer, i am creating ePub reader for reading ePub files.

I have plist in my iphone app and I want to read and write data to my .plist file, in which i am facing problem.

here is my code snippet,

**Logic:** first i am downloading an ePub file, `.ePub` file will be downloaded to this path

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
NSLog(@"basePath=%@",basePath);
```

output :-
    =`/Users/krunal/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/6B7FCD58-EDF9-44F4-8B33-5F3542536F92/Documents`

now, i want to write name of Downloaded  `.ePub`file into  file into my `.plist`

`code:`

```
NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: basePath];

    [data setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:value] forKey:@"value"];

    [data writeToFile: plistPath atomically:YES];
    [data release];
```

i tried this, but i am unable to write in my `.plist` file.

***Any Help Will be Appriciated.***

**Thanks In Advance !!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: plistPath];
```

?

---

untested code follows:

Step 1: Copy the file to it's folder.

```
NSError *error1;
BOOL resourcesAlreadyInDocumentsDirectory;
BOOL copied1;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath1 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/epub.plist"];

resourcesAlreadyInDocumentsDirectory = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath1];

if(resourcesAlreadyInDocumentsDirectory == YES) {

} else {

    NSString *path1 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingFormat:@"/epub.plist"];
    copied1 = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:path1 toPath:filePath1 error:&error1];

    if (!copied1) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to copy epub.plist. Error %@", [error1 localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Step 2:Open it

```
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath1];
```

Step 3:Write data to it

```
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:value] forKey:@"value"];
[dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: In that file: Firstly you're trying to move a file from the documents folder when you should be copying it. However, you're trying to move it without actually doing anything : there is no fileManager defined to do the work. Next you're trying to move it to a path that hasn't been defined. There's no wonder that you can't open a file that doesn't exist, let alone write to it.

Comment: Step 1:) Copy the file to it's folder

Comment: can you plz suggest some code snippet, i am very new to iPad.

Comment: i tried your EDIT, Thanx for the help, but still i am getting at SIGABRT if(!copied1) condition http://pastebin.com/N3tHVHWD

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11377/discussion-between-krunal-and-ade)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: basePath];
```

*data* is nil here, you should init it with:

```
NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Edited my answer to be more clear:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
if ( basePath == nil ) {
     return
}
NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[data setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:value] forKey:@"value"];
NSString *plistPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/name.plist", basePath];
[data writeToFile: plistPath atomically:YES];
[data release];
```

Comment: So [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] returns nil to you? It's weird! Check your code, as I tested my answer in a test project and it worked well.

Comment: I think the wrong part is that you save a NSDictionary and then load a NSArray. If you want an array create a NSArray of NSDictionary and save it instead.

Comment: can you plz suggest some code snippet, i am very new to iPad.

Answer (score 0):

It is easer for you to use NSUserDefault, you data will be saved to a plist file as following code:

```
- (void)setOverviewGroupInstrument:(BOOL)isGroupded {
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setObject:[Your array] forKey:[Your Key]];
[prefs synchronize];
}
```

Then you can read by:

```
- (NSMutableArray*)getOverviewInstrumentList {
    return [prefs objectForKey:[Your Key]];
}
```